# Why doesn't my recently downloaded font work?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-family

I've just installed a new text font called `Skyfont`. Can't get it to work and I've been declaring it with `@font-face` and there is no element in the html that should block it. Here's the CSS code:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Skyfont Regular';
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 26pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 26px;
    right: 50%;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Skyfont Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Skyfont Regular'), url(fonts/Skyfont-NonCommercial.otf) format('otf');
}
```

Thanks for all help I can get :) I

f there is anything missing that I haven't written, please tell me.

Comment: Are you getting an error if you look in the browser / web developer tools?

Comment: Hi @Ritze, did my clues lead to an answer? In that case, it is always helpful and much appreciated to mark it as a solution. Otherwise, I would be happy to help you investigate the problem further.

Answer (score 1):

A few plausible explanations:

- you forgot the quotes around the url path in the `src` property
- you are targeting the wrong path. Have a look at the developer console of your browser to check whether your are successfully requesting the font file or not. You can open it by pressing Control+Shift+J (or Command+Option+J on Mac) in `Chrome` or Control+Shift+K (or Command+Option+K on Mac). Head over to the `network` window and reload the page. Try to find the name of the font file (which should be Skyfont-NonCommercial.otf according to your `css`). You should see a `200` status next to it, meaning your browser successfully fetched the file. If not, it means your file cannot be found at the given address (for other HTTP status codes, see [here](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)).
- your `.otf` file is corrupted or has the wrong file extension

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is strange browser behavior with fonts installed locally in Windows 10.
If you drag fonts files to C:\Windows\Fonts windows installs them into user profile
C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts.
Chrome won't see that font in @font-face tag, so local('Skyfont Regular') will never work.
This may be unexpected consequence of this bug, that got fixed recently [@font-face src: local() should take *font face* name, not *family* name](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=627143)
Workaround is to install fonts into C:\Windows\Fonts, you can do this by right-clicking fonts files and choose 'Install fonts for all users'.